# Excel VBA macro - values

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following situation:
There is a main folder with a large number of sub-folders. In each of these sub-folders there are 3-4 PDFs and usually one Excel file. I have now built a macro which, after pressing a button and selecting the main folder, copied certain columns of the Excel files of all subfolders and put them together on a worksheet. The basic copying process works, but the following problems have arisen:

1. I want only the values of the cells and not the functions to be copied. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a working solution to this.
2. It rarely happens that there is more than one Excel file in a subfolder. If this is the case, the contents of both files should also be copied. At the moment only the content of one file is copied. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a solution here either.

I would be very grateful if someone could help me here.

```
Sub FolderNames()
'Update 20141027
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim xPath As String
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim fso As Object, j As Long, folder1 As Object
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Choose the folder"
    .Show
End With
On Error Resume Next
xPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1) & "\"
'Application.Workbooks.Add
Set xWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FolderList")
xWs.Cells.Clear
xWs.Cells(1, 1).Value = xPath
xWs.Cells(2, 1).Value = "Path"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder1 = fso.GetFolder(xPath)
getSubFolder folder1

xWs.Range("1:2").Delete xlUp
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Sub getSubFolder(ByRef prntfld As Object)
Dim SubFolder As Object
Dim subfld As Object
Dim xRow As Long
For Each SubFolder In prntfld.SubFolders
    xRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FolderList").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FolderList").Cells(xRow, 1) = SubFolder.Path
Next SubFolder
For Each subfld In prntfld.SubFolders
    getSubFolder subfld
Next subfld
End Sub



Sub getfiles()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim oFSO As Object
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim oFile As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim lrow As Long
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim FileFound As Boolean
Dim targetfile As Workbook
Dim firstfile As Boolean
firstfile = True
lrow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FolderList").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim filecount As Long
filecount = 0
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Konsolidierung").Cells.Clear

For j = 1 To lrow
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FolderList").Cells(j, 1).Text)

    filecount = filecount + 1

For Each oFile In oFolder.Files

    If Right(oFile.Name, 4) = "xlsx" Then
    FileFound = True
    Set targetfile = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FolderList").Cells(j, 1).Text & "\" & oFile.Name)
    
    If firstfile Then
    targetfile.Sheets(1).Range("A:F").Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Konsolidierung").Cells(1, 1)
    firstfile = False
    Else
    
    targetfile.Sheets(1).Range("F:F").Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Konsolidierung").Cells(1, filecount + 5)
    End If
    
    targetfile.Close False
    
        
    End If
    
    
    

Next oFile

If FileFound = False Then
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Konsolidierung").Cells(1, filecount + 5) = "Keine Datei gefunden"
Else
FileFound = False
End If

Next j


Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Try copy/pastevalues instead of the straight copy.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I was able to solve the problem.